# Group by multiple Values in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am facing a bit of an issue here.
The goal is to group a collection using 4 values, which are `Origin.PositionCoordinates.X`, `Origin.PositionCoordinates.Y`, `Destination.PositionCoordinates.X`, `Destination.PositionCoordinates.Y`.

I get error stating:

> anonymous types can not have multiple properties with same name.

I can not change the design (can not change class properties). Is there a solution to deal with this? Below is the sample code I am struggling with.

```
 private bool EdgeCollectionIsAppropriate(Dictionary<int, DijkstraEdge> theEdges)
 {
    if (theEdges.GroupBy(variable => new { 
            variable.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.X, 
            variable.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.Y,
            variable.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.X, 
            variable.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.Y }).Any(x=>x.Count()>1))
    {
        logger.Debug("The edges list contains 2 or more edges with same destnation and origin position");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you are creating an anonymous type with 2 properties with name `X`.
Instead give explicit names to the fields: (you don't have to do to all of them. Just to the one with the conflicting name is enough)

```
theEdges.GroupBy(v=> new { 
    OriginX = v.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.X, 
    OriginY = v.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.Y,
    v.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.X,
    v.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.Y })
```

Also it is not clear writing it all in the if statement. Instead store the query's result in a variable and then use the if statement:

```
var dupDestAndOrigin = theEdges.GroupBy(v=> new { 
                                      OriginX = v.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.X, 
                                      OriginY = v.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.Y,
                                      v.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.X,
                                      v.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.Y })
                               .Any(x => x.Count() > 1);    
if(dupDestAndOrigin)
{
    // TODO - log
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give them a different name. You cannot have 2 Xs and 2Ys properties in the same object.

```
 private bool EdgeCollectionIsAppropriate(Dictionary<int, DijkstraEdge> theEdges)
     {

        if (theEdges.GroupBy(variable => new { A=variable.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.X, B=variable.Value.Origin.PositionCoordinates.Y,C=variable.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.X, D=variable.Value.Destination.PositionCoordinates.Y }).Any(x=>x.Count()>1))


        {
            logger.Debug("The edges list contains 2 or more edges with same destnation and origin position");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```